# Chef recipe to read from data bag and write to .SSH directory

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

I am trying to use the super useful `chef data bag` to store private keys that allows me access to a SFTP server. Now, the nodes that are managed by `chef` in my case each need to have these `private keys` in their `.ssh` directories.

So far I have been able to create a new `data bag` by doing this:

`knife data bag create keys mySFTP` where `keys` is the bag and `mySFTP` is an item on it. This item looks like this:

```
id:       nifi
password: This is all the password that we will ever need. oashdkjashdk28374983q7489ahskjdhaskjdhq834y93q4 HEHEHE
```

** Please note that I am indeed using encrypted data bags which is not shown here.

Now, I think I will need to create a recipe that can read the private key and push it down to all the nodes. Can I use a file template to create a new file named `mySFTP.key` and try to dump the private key from the data bag?

My direct question is: How do I write my receipe that will be able to read the data stored in my data bag and write the contents to the `.ssh` directory. Finally, the node should be able to connect to my SFTP server.

Comment: Try going through https://learn.chef.io as it will really help you get around the bases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a `file` or `template` resource. With a `file` resource you would specify the content directly in the recipe code, with a `template` you use a Erb template and pass the value in through the `variables` property.

Comment: How do I access the variables inside the databag to be used in my file resource script?

Comment: The `data_bag_item` helper function returns something you can use like a normal Hash. So `x = data_bag_item('keys', 'mySFTP')` and `variables password: x['password']` or something like that.